# Convert Nested JSON to CSV with constants in NiFi

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi and working on a small POC that gets data in JSON format. The Json should then be converted to CSV. I have amanged to get this working when the JSON has a well defined structure, say a 1 to 1 on key:value pairs, but what I'm trying to do is convert the following:

```
{
  "id": "SS01-P001-I001",
  "timestamp": "2020-04-26 11:55:44.774604-04:00",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "SS01-P001-I001-0",
      "value": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "SS01-P001-I001-1",
      "value": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "SS01-P001-I001-2",
      "value": "0.0"
      }
    ]
  }
```

into this:

```
timestamp, id, name, value
"2020-04-26 11:55:44.774604-04:00", "SS01-P001-I001", "SS01-P001-I001-0", 0.0
"2020-04-26 11:55:44.774604-04:00", "SS01-P001-I001", "SS01-P001-I001-1", 0.0
"2020-04-26 11:55:44.774604-04:00", "SS01-P001-I001", "SS01-P001-I001-2", 0.0
```

Where I get stuck is using the two constants (timestamp, id) in the NiFi flowfile content JSON over and over for each iteration of name and value.

I hope this is enough information for some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the input JSON into "rows" using JoltTransformJSON with the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,timestamp)": "[&1].timestamp",
          "@(2,id)": "[&1].id",
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then you can use ConvertRecord to convert from JSON to CSV. Alternatively you could try ForkRecord to split on the `data` array with "Include Parent Fields" set to `true` and a CSVRecordSetWriter. If the forked flowfiles are not in the correct format, you could use a processor like JoltTransformRecord or UpdateRecord to get it into the desired format.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the help. I had tried to put my own jolt spec together and got a structure down but did not know how to iterate over the data.